# Wordpress: Data from database in custom php files

Tags: wordpress

I have never done anything like this before, that's why I ask for some tips how to solve this problem.
I have website which has following links:
**Home, Product, Blog, About us, Contact**

In Blog section I have installed Wordpress. And here is my problem/question:
How can I manage the rest of the pages? I don't know if Wordpress allow manage custom files, so I probably will need to create class to retrieve data from database and put it in these files. 
I'm wondering if there is any API, plugins, which could let me help in this.
Any tips for solving my problem, are welcome and appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the wordpress should be installed for the entire site.

and than what you can do is just make pages, even custom pages with different design for each page on the site.

you can read more about it her:[Codex/Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates)

and than in the **blog** page you can just create a link to a category or to the regular posts in the system.

Answer (score 2):

you can load wordpress environment in other php pages by using

```
require( 'blog/wp-load.php' );
```

where 'blog' being your wordpress install root.